# Retrieve audio from Gather action

Tags: twilio

I am using the Gather action with `dtmf speech` as the input. Is it possible to retrieve the raw audio if the user decides to speak? Basically, I'm looking for something similar to what the Record action does, but while still giving the user the choice to either speak or use keypresses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) with input `dtmf speech` does not make the raw audio available.

What do you want to use the audio for? How would you expect to receive it? I'd be happy to send this feedback to the team if you can share.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm working on a survey-like application in which users answer questions and I record their answers using the `Record` action. One of the questions is a multiple choice, and so I want to give users the option to answer through keypresses or through speech. I tried looking into ways to combine the `Record` and `Gather` actions, but AFAIK nesting isn't allowed with `Record`.

Comment: You're right, `<Record>` is not supported within `<Gather>`. While I understand why you might want to offer DTMF or speech responses to multiple choice I don't think you can make that happen right now. It's probably best to stick with one or the other. I'll forward this case to the team to see what they think for the future though.